# Input value should change as I type and not just on enter on focus is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am totally new to coding. Please help. I want to change #tag value every time I type. Here is my html with jquery. Tag is id for input.Its value gets changed only on pressing somewhere else or enter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
           #<input type="text" id="tag" class="hash"/> 
           <button>submit</button>
        </form>

        <div id="tweets"></div>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('/link');

            $('.hash').change(function(){
                $('#tweet').after();
                socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val()); //change #tag value every time I type
                $('#tag').val('');

                return;

            });

            socket.on('message', function(msg){
                $('#tweets').after($('<div>').text(msg));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: You may be looking for the keyup event instead of change. E.g. `$('.hash').on('keyup', function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

Use onkeydown or onkeypress HTML DOM

ex:

```
<form>
   #<input type="text" id="tag" class="hash" 
        onkeypress="socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val());" /> 
   <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Everytime you press a button on the keyboard, the command

```
  socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val())
```

will be fired

Answer (score 0):

Do it in following way use keyUp instead of change

```
$('.hash').on('keyup',function(){
     $('#tweet').after();
     socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val()); //change #tag value every time I type
     $('#tag').val('');

     return;

   });
```